# how to check if sails.js project is development or production and load some custom code according to that?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

how to check if sails.js project is development or production and load some custom code according to that?
So that if I'm lifting sails in development mode, I want to load different files/code and if the project is lifted in production mode then use different code.
A simple solution with a single if condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.env.NODE_ENV` is pretty standard however sails has variable that is also makes available `sails.config.environment` and is in the global scope by default.

Another method would be to place the code in the corresponding environment named js file (ex develoment.js) inside the `config/env` folder

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/env

Comment: if try to access `sails.config.environment` in config e.g. session.js, it gives error `ReferenceError: sails is not defined` however `process.env.NODE_ENV` works everywhere

Answer (score 3):

found it!

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'){
    // do something
}else{

}
```